# Removing random items from a list

Tags: python, list, random

So basically i have 10 txt files(named A_1,A_2........A_10), i want to randomly select 3 files out of these 10 in a way, when those 3 files are randomly chosen, they will be removed from the original list and a new list can be created using the randomly chosen 3 files.I tried the following method, but when i try the command print(filelist), it still shows the 10 txt files,Any suggestion or advice will be really helpful.

```
import random
filelist=[]
for i in list(range(1,11)):
    filelist.append("/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_%s.txt" %i)
Newlist=random.sample(filelist,4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of elements in `filelist` don't matter to you, you can:

Shuffle `filelist` take first `n` elements to for an `new_list`, and reassign remaining elements to `filelist`

```
In [48]: import random as rn

In [49]: filelist = range(10)

In [50]: rn.shuffle(filelist)

In [51]: new_list = filelist[:3]

In [52]: filelist = filelist[3:]

In [53]: new_list
Out[53]: [3, 4, 5]

In [54]: filelist
Out[54]: [9, 8, 7, 6, 1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: So basically i am stuck at the next phase, as i have another 10 txt files named (B_1,B_2.......B_10). The A and B files are basically the same source files with different parameters, now as i have randomly taken out 3 (from 10 A files) out of my list(in your code its A_3,A_4 and A_5), any suggestion on how can i take out the corresponding B files also(B_3,B_4 and B_5) as using random will not take out the corresponding Bs of As.

Comment: @Hrihaan, there is certainly a way to do it, perhaps you can represent you data a little differently, for example: `filelistB = [("B", 2), ("B", 3), ("B", 4), ("B", 5)]`, then you can just filter out all elements with have `3` and `4` as second element.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `random.sample` will give you a random sample of items from the list, but it won't remove any items. One solution to this is to `pop` at a random index from the `filelist` list, and add the returned value to a list, `newlist`.

Suppose you have:

```
import random
filelist = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']                                    # List containing the file names
newlist = []                                                           # Initialize a list that will contain the removed file names
for i in range(3):                                                     # We want to remove 3 files
    newlist.append(filelist.pop(random.randint(0, len(filelist) - 1))) # Pop an item out of the file list at random in the range between 0 and the length of the file list and add it to the new list
```